# Why is RDS Instance Stuck at Starting State?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance that I stopped a few days ago. Everytime I start it back up, it will be stuck at `starting` state for a while until it goes back to `stopped` state.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you operate on AWS console. You can check "logs & events" tab of specific RDS instance.
Logs section, to be more specific. Name of files depends on your DB engine version.
I would sort with "last written" column and check what in the logs.
In [official Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html) there is more details, also for AWS CLI.